# How to include Zumo API version header in rest client

Tags: web-services, rest, azure, http-headers

I have an Azure Mobile App backend working web service. I am trying to carry out basic crud operations. I understand that you can use a url like myapp/tables/object?zumo-api-version=2.0.0 and this works fine when I am getting data. However, when I want to put, delete etc it requires an id. If I type myapp/tables/object/dsjkfhsdjkfjsdfjkkdjf?zumo-api-version=2.0.0 for example where the string is the id I can carry out the operation. Similarly, if I enter an id in Swagger, I can also carry out the put operation. However, I am unsure as to how to go about adding the zumo-api-version details on the client side. How can I include the zumo version header in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **Header Specification** here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/

> The key **ZUMO-API-VERSION** may be specified in either the HTTP header or the query string. The value is a version string in the form x.y.z.
>
> For example:
> GET https://service.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem
> HEADERS: `ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0`
>
> POST https://service.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

So you could do:

```bash
$ curl -sv -H "ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0" \
       http://{mobileapp}.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem

> GET /tables/todoitem HTTP/1.1
> Host: {mobileapp}.azurewebsites.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]    

[{
    "id":"40b996d6-ec7f-4188-a310-0f02808e7093",
    "createdAt":"2016-08-31T11:30:11.955Z",
    "updatedAt":"2016-08-31T11:30:11.971Z",
    "version":"AAAAAAAAG5s=",
    "deleted":false,
    "Yo_mobileapp":"Sup"
}]
```

Note `ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0` passed in as Header.
If you're asking "Which is better?", there's no better. They do the same thing. That being said, it's probably easier and cleaner to send a Header for most use cases.

Comment: Thanks. Just getting back to this now. I managed to add the header. var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0"); However, I am still getting an error on my PUT - simply says "Method Not Allowed" in debugger - even though when I paste the absolute URI from the debugger into the browser I get the resource!! Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind.. everything is 200 OK! Thanks for your help.